# How to find last occurrence of an element using FindLast()

Tags: c#, list

I want to find the last occurrence of an element in a list and know I must use the FindLast() to do that. However, I don't know how to implement and use this method.

Here is the code that I have:

```
// the list I need to check
orderedMetricsByNS = (List<Metric>) lmresponse.Metrics.OrderBy(metric => metric.Namespace);

foreach (Metric m in orderedMetricsByNS)
            {
                 // want to use the FindLast() here 
            }
```

How do I retrieve the last occurrence of a metric like this? Thanks

Comment: As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kthb929(v=vs.110).aspx) says.

Comment: Yeah I know what it does. I am trying to use it in an if-statement so that I can call another method afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `Predicate`? You can use it like this:

```
var item = orderedMetricsByNS.FindLast(m => /* your condition */);
```

Or if you wanna just find the last item use `Last` method

```
var item = orderedMetricsByNS.Last();
```

Btw you can't cast from `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`, your code will fail, you need to use `ToList` method.

```
orderedMetricsByNS = lmresponse.Metrics.OrderBy(metric => metric.Namespace).ToList();
```

Comment: There should be no need to cast to `List<T>`; there is an overload of `Last` that takes a condition -- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't know how to use/setup a Predicate. But what I want to do is retrieve the last occurrence of an element.

Comment: @ZevSpitz yes it is needed if you are gonna use FindLast

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ:

```
var last = orderedMetricByNS.LastOrDefault();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault%28v=vs.95%29.aspx